# access denied finding property "hwservicemanager.ready"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to do an animation in my app but when I click on button t do animation my app crashes and logcat gives this error

"access denied finding property "hwservicemanager.ready" "
Please help me to fix it

```
 signup_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class);
            // startActivity(intent);

            //Attach all the elements those you want to animate in design
            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[7];
            pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(logo_image, "logo_image");
            pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(logoText, "logo_text");
            pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(sloganText, "logo_desc");
            pairs[3] = new Pair<View, String>(username, "username_tran");
            pairs[4] = new Pair<View, String>(password, "password_tran");
            pairs[5] = new Pair<View, String>(login_btn, "login_button_tran");
            pairs[6] = new Pair<View, String>(signup_btn, "signup_button_tran");

            //wrap the call in API level 21 or higher
            // if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Login.this, pairs);
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            // }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a smartphone to run the app, you can change de usb mode. In my case, worked just fine setting usb mode to "PTB via USB" turned on, but you can try all until you got it.

Sorry about my english, im Brazilian.

Comment: helped me to remove to many unnecessary logs